# Webpack2 + babel all but one js file are converted to es5

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, vuejs2

I'm using webpack and babel to convert my js and vue2 files to es5 and compile into a single build.js

This is my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["latest", 'stage-1'],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-es2015-arrow-functions"
    ],
    "comments": false
}
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

require("babel-polyfill");

module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src'],
    output: {
        path: './dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        scss: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                        styl: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'stylus-loader',
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {

        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
    },

    plugins: [
        // new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        //   'process.env': {
        //     'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        //   }
        // })
    ]
}
```

Running the following command, successfuly compiles all js and vue files including the imported ones into build.js

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --watch --display-error-details
```

All es6 compatible codes are converted to es5 except for BaseModal.js in https://github.com/vue-bulma/modal/

BaseModal.js resides in node_modules/vue-bulma-modal/src/ and is imported by Modal.vue in the same package

I import Modal over index.js of the same package by

```
import {Modal} from 'vue-bulma-modal'
```

and BaseModal.js ends up in build.js as it is, without being converted to es5.

But if i copy Modal.vue and BaseModal.js directly into my code and update the import paths accordingly , it is converted to es5 just fine without any problems.

What is it that I'm doing wrong in my webpack.config.js?

Comment: You have `exclude: /node_modules/` on `babel-loader`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth i've also tried with that line disabled. takes more time, but the result is the same